# Pass typescript arrow function in text (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular project, I use a [3rd party message display component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/messages) to display error text to the user. For some messages, I want to be able to have a clickable link which will give the user some more context about what they can do to fix the error. I do not want the link to redirect the user, but instead change a boolean variable which will show a message box with more information.

I.E.

```
//In the component
let callback = ()=>{this.showAdditionalInfoBox = true; }
let detail = `Some message <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="${callback}">More Info</a>`;
let safeDetail = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(detail);
this.messageService.add({
     severity:'error', 
     summary:'Something Happened', 
     detail:safeDetail
});
```

Once the message is rendered, onclick looks like this:

```
onclick="function(){ _this.showAdditionalInfoBox = true;}"
```

When clicked, I get an error messsage saying that `_this` is not defined. Which tells me that the arrow function's closure did not come with it because `_this` is supposed to be a pointer to my component.

Is there some way I can get the arrow function to translate all the way through? Any other way that I can attach a click handler to this dynamically created html element?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: I second: not possible.

Comment: why don't you try to pass context into function, like `let callback = (context)=>{context.showAdditionalInfoBox = true; }`, not tried at all, just a suggestion...

Comment: @MadhuRanjan The `<a>` element doesn't know what context is and cant pass it in. `context` is undefined

Comment: Fair enough, arrow functions cannot be converted to a string and still have their closures. Is there another way I am not seeing where I can provide an `<a>` tag which when clicked ultimately sets `this.showAdditionalInfoBox` to true?

Comment: @spectacularbob, check my answer.

Comment: this is more trouble than just making your own message component or finding a library that supports templates in messages.

Comment: It would be a good feature request for PrimeNG to add their pTemplate to their messages and growls.

Comment: I made a feature request https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/4317 but its not currently possible w/o a hack. agree with @bryan60 to find lib with message templates or making our own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the HTML you are rendering is outside angular scope and will run like a regular JavaScript function, you will need to get the reference of your component class and then use some of its method,

To achieve that, register your component class with global window variable in `OnInit` life cycle hook,

```
ngOnInit(){
     window.myapp = this;
}
```

then you may simply consume any component function like below,

```
 ...
 window.myapp.<function in your component>
 ...
```

So you may update your detail message like below,

```
onClick() {
     let callback = "window.myapp.superHack(); return false;";
     let detail = `Some message <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="${callback}">More Info</a>`;
     let safeDetail = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(detail);
     this.messageService.add({
       severity:'error', 
       summary:'Something Happened', 
       detail:safeDetail
     });
}
```

Now since the function is used from outside of angular, you need to utilize `NgZone` to make Model change fire changeDetection.

```
superHack = () => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.someVar = "new value";
    });
}
```

do not forget to destroy object from global reference.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
   delete  window.myapp;
}
```

Here is complete example in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N759UQ?p=preview)!!

Comment: Its not pretty, but it works. Writing a message library or asking primeng to add this feature to theirs is probably cleaner